# how could I read multiple series in one xlsx file and save in .mat?

Tags: matlab, import

First sorry for basic questions..

What I've done was importing ".csv" to matlab using "readtable. But I don't have idea as to making this 367 different time series to be independent .mat files.

```
result = readtable('price.csv');
```

result is shown in image file to help understanding..
[image]

How could I make this process automatically?? Please help me..

Comment: Google 'for loop matlab' and 'save matlab'

Answer (score 0):

```
result = readtable('price.csv');
for i = 1:2:734
    M = rmmissing(result(:,[i,i+1]));
    str = M.Properties.VariableNames(2);
    % str{1}(regexp(str{1}, 'x')) = [];
    name = str{1};
    save(['C:\Users\bok\Desktop\mat\',name],'M');
end
```

Comment: Add some description to your answer

Comment: I'm sure the code is correct, but it needs further description as to how it solved the problem